# pivot on multiple columns based on single column giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Guys I am running into a problem where I am trying to pivot on 2 columns based on the same column.
In the below example, I want to pivot the columns `ProductExternalFullName` and `Coverage` both basesd on the `Code` value. However 
sql server will not let me do that. Is there any work around for this?

The other part of the problem is that I cannot include the grain (candidate key), in the subquery. The pivot does not work correctly if I have the candidate key.
If I could had been able to do that, I could have solved this in few ways.

[image]

SCRIPTS for this:

```
IF (object_id('TblPivot','U') > 0)
DROP TABLE TblPivot

CREATE TABLE TblPivot
(
    ApplicationConsumerID int,
    Relationship varchar(25),
    Code varchar(100),
    ProductExternalFullName varchar(50),
    Coverage varchar(50)
)

GO

INSERT INTO TblPivot(ApplicationConsumerID, Relationship, Code, ProductExternalFullName, Coverage) VALUES
  (5730, 'Employee', 'MED1', 'Medical Plan1', 'Emp Only')
, (5730, 'Employee', 'DEN1', 'Dental Low Plan1', 'Emp Only')
, (5730, 'Employee', 'IDT1', 'Identity Theft Protection Plan1', 'Emp+Family')
```

My Attempt:
The problem is that Sql Server wont let me pivot on 2 columns based on value of one column

```
select *
 from 
(   SELECT 
    de.ApplicationConsumerID,
    CASE WHEN RelationShip = 'Not Found' THEN 'Employee' ELSE DependentRelationshipTypeName END AS Relationship


     ,CASE WHEN DependentRelationshipTypeName = 'Not Found' THEN Code ELSE NULL END as Code
    ,CASE WHEN DependentRelationshipTypeName = 'Not Found' THEN ProductExternalFullName ELSE NULL END as ProductExternalFullName
    ,CASE WHEN DependentRelationshipTypeName = 'Not Found' THEN  CoverageTierNameELSE NULL END as CoverageTierName
    FROM        
    TblPivot
) as  a
PIVOT (MAX(a.ProductExternalFullName) FOR a.CODE IN (DEN, IDT, MED)) as pvt
PIVOT (MAX(a.CoverageTierName) FOR a.CODE IN (DEN, IDT, MED)) as pvt
```

Comment: How can we help with your query if you don't show it in your question?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Done

Comment: For starters your query includes DependentRelationshipTypeName , which isn't in the example table you provided. What is this column?

Comment: Its aliased as Relationship, so you can assume these 2 to be same.